# Google places is not defined even after including the module correctly

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a page with a bootstrap modal, this modal has a form in it, when I submit this form, this form should be submitted and I have used action atrribute and redirected all the form data to another page.

I used google maps api in both the pages

It is working fine in the first page, but when the form is submitted and the page has been redirected to another page, then I'm getting an error which says google.places is not defined.

Please take a look the code that I have written so far :

firstPage.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/loading-bar.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/autocomplete.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sweetalert-min.css">
      <script src="../js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">



<div class="dash1">
    <div class="row stats-profile-picture">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div id="profile-change"></div>
            <p class="text-center  text-uppercase font-weight-bold" id="dbProfileName"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 profile-details" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <p><strong>#TWT005</strong></p>
            <p><strong>GST NO : 123456</strong></p>
            <p><strong>+91 9030590437</strong></p>
        </div>
        <a ui-sref="customerBooking.pending" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="bookings">
                <p class="text-center"><img src="images/Pending-icon.png" alt="Pending" width="30%"></p>
                <p class="text-center big-numbers"><strong>06</strong></p>
                <p class="text-center"><strong>Pending</strong></p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a ui-sref="customerBooking.confirmed" class="col-md-2">
            <p class="text-center"><img src="images/Confirmed-icon.png" alt="Confirmed icon" width="30%"></p>
            <p class="text-center big-numbers"><strong>06</strong></p>
            <p class="text-center"><strong>Confirmed</strong></p>
        </a>
        <a ui-sref="customerBooking.completed" class="col-md-2" style="border-right: none">
            <p class="text-center"><img src="images/list.png" alt="completed" width="30%"></p>
            <p class="text-center big-numbers"><strong>06</strong></p>
            <p class="text-center"><strong>Completed</strong></p>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="custom-dashed-border"></div>
<div class="container main-options">
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 cards" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-booking">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 9%;">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p class="text-center">
                        <img src="images/notebook.svg" width="60%" alt="notepad"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-top: 3%;">
                    <p class="big-font"><strong>New Booking</strong></p>
                    <p class="small-font"><strong>Make a new Booking</strong></p>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
<!-- Modal for new Booking -->
<div id="new-booking" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="get" action="SearchRedesign.html" name="target" id="target"
                  style="padding: 5px" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="text-center col-md-12">
                        <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray; padding-bottom: 5px;">New Booking</span>
                    </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="fromPlace">From </label>
                            <input class="form-control" tabindex="1" autofocus  g-places-autocomplete
                                   force-selection="true" options="autocompleteOptions"  ng-model="fromPlace"
                                   placeholder="From Place" autocomplete="off" id="fromPlace" name="fromPlace">
                            <input ng-cloak type="hidden" name="sourceAddressLat" ng-model="sourceAddressLat" value="{{sourceAddressLat}}"
                                   id="fromLat">
                            <input ng-cloak type="hidden" name="sourceAddressLang" ng-model="sourceAddressLang" value="{{sourceAddressLang}}"
                                   id="fromLong">
                            <input ng-cloak type="hidden" name="sourceAddress" ng-model="sourceAddress" value="{{sourceAddress}}"
                                   id="fromCity" required>
                            <p ng-cloak ng-show="target.fromPlace.$touched && target.sourceAddress.$invalid" class="text-danger"><strong>Please enter a valid place</strong></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="toPlace">To</label>
                            <input class="form-control" tabindex="2"  id="toPlace" name="toPlace" g-places-autocomplete force-selection="true"
                                   options="autocompleteOptions" placeholder="To Place" autocomplete="off" ng-model="toPlace">
                            <input ng-cloak type="hidden" name="destinationAddressLat" ng-model="destinationAddressLat"
                                   value="{{destinationAddressLat}}" id="toLat">
                            <input ng-cloak type="hidden" name="destinationAddressLang" ng-model="destinationAddressLang"
                                   value="{{destinationAddressLang}}" id="toLong">
                            <input ng-cloak type="hidden" name="destinationAddress" ng-model="destinationAddress"
                                   value="{{destinationAddress}}" id="toCity" required>
                            <p ng-cloak ng-show="target.toPlace.$touched && target.destinationAddress.$invalid" class="text-danger"><strong>Please enter a valid place</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div  class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="datepicker">Date of load:</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="date" tabindex="3" id="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="Date" ng-model="datepicker"
                                           autocomplete="off" required>
                                    <p ng-cloak ng-show="target.date.$touched && target.date.$error.required" class="text-danger"><strong>Please select the date to continue</strong></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="reportTime">Time :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="reportTime" id="reportTime" ng-model="reportTime" class="form-control" tabindex="4" style="display: inline;" required/>
                                    <p ng-cloak ng-show="target.reportTime.$touched && target.reportTime.$error.required" class="text-danger"><strong>Please select the time to continue</strong></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="material_type">Material Type:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" ng-change="update()" name="materialTypeHome" id="material_type"
                                    ng-options="option as option for option in materialTypeOptions" ng-model="material_type"
                                    tabindex="7" required>
                                <option value="">Please choose</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="weight">Capacity<span
                                            style="font-size: 9px;padding-left:1px;">(tons)</span>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                                              title="Total Capacity of your Load" style="cursor: pointer"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" min="0.1" value="1" max="30" name="weight" style="display: inline;"
                                           tabindex="5" placeholder="In tons" id="weight" type="number" step="any">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="noOfTrucks">No of Trucks
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="tooltip1" data-placement="bottom"
                                              title="How many trucks required for your Load" style="cursor: pointer"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" value="1" max="1000" step="1"
                                           name="noOfTrucks" style="display: inline;" tabindex="6" placeholder="No Of Trucks"
                                           id="noOfTrucks" required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="truck_type">Type of truck </label>

                            <select class="form-control" ng-options="option as option for option in truckTypeOptions" id="truck_type"
                                    ng-model="truck_type" tabindex="7" name="truckTypeHome" required>
                                <option value="">Please choose</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-4 offset-md-4">Search&nbsp;
                            <img src="images/white-mag-glass.png" style="width:18px;height: 18px;margin-bottom: 5px;"/></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="js/customer-main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cards.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/state.js"> </script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/autocomplete-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/transForm.js"></script>

  </body>


</html>
```

Second-page.html (page where the form data is redirected )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
<head>
    <!-- for-mobile-apps -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        addEventListener("load", function () {
            setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
        }, false);
        function hideURLbar() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        } </script>

    <!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/autocomplete.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/newModel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ng-notify/0.6.0/ng-notify.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../newui/css/newdropdown.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dropdown.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sweetalert-min.css">
    <!-- js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../newui/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('.loader').fadeOut('Slow');
        })
    </script>-->
    <script src="../js/atmosphere.js"></script>
    <!-- FlexSlider -->

    <!-- //js -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic'
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>

<body  id="index"  ng-controller="searchCtrl">
<!--<div class="loader"></div>-->
<!-- header -->
</body>


    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="../text/javascript" src="js/autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ng-notify/0.6.0/ng-notify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/dirPagination.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/notificationDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <!-- angularjs controller file -->
    <!-- angularjs controller file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/searchRedesign.js"></script>
```

SecondpageJS:

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['google.places','ui.bootstrap','ngNotify','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','notificationsTruckway']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not correctly loading the API on your second page.

On both pages you have the line:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Make sure you are actually correctly replacing `YOUR_API_KEY` with your key from google on both pages.